# data are not added to the database in php , pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my project i have sales part for that invoice is included. Therefore I have 2 tables , One is master table named invoice (includes invoice id , grand total, tax, date, net total, sub total etc ..) and other is item table invoiceitemtable  (includes itemID, item_no, item_qty , item_price , item_totPrice) .

This is the code for **_invoice.php**

```
<?php

require_once '../../config/config.php';
try {

$invoice_ID = $_POST['invoice_ID'];
$tbl_employee_tbl_branch_branch_ID = $_SESSION['Branch'];
$inoice_subTot1 = $_POST['inoice_subTot'];
$invoice_tax1 = $_POST['invoice_tax'];
$invoice_discount1 = $_POST['invoice_discount'];
$invoice_grandTot1 = $_POST['invoice_grandTot'];
$tbl_employee_NIC = $_SESSION['username'];

$inoice_subTot = substr($inoice_subTot1,3);
$invoice_tax = substr($invoice_tax1,3);
$invoice_discount = substr($invoice_discount1,3);
$invoice_grandTot = substr($invoice_grandTot1,3);


    foreach ($_POST['invoiceItem_itemIDS'] as $rowIndex => $item_selected) {

   $invoiceItem_itemID1 =  $_POST['invoiceItem_itemIDS'][$rowIndex];
   $invoiceItem_itemID = round($invoiceItem_itemID1);
   $invoiceItem_qty = $_POST['invoiceItem_qtyS'][$rowIndex];
   $invoiceItem_price  =  $_POST['invoiceItem_itemPriceS'][$rowIndex];
   $invoiceItem_totPrice1 =  $_POST['invoiceItem_totPriceS'][$rowIndex];
   $invoiceItem_totPrice = substr($invoiceItem_totPrice1,3);




   echo 'ITEM ID'.$invoiceItem_itemID.'<BR/>'; 
   echo 'QUANTITY'.$invoiceItem_qty.'<BR/>';
   echo 'ITEM PRICE'.$invoiceItem_itemPrice.'<BR/>';
   echo 'ITEM TOTAL'.$invoiceItem_totPrice.'<BR/>';
  echo $invoice_ID ;    

//  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO `tbl_invoiceitem`(`invoiceItem_itemID`,"
//           . " `invoiceItem_qty`, "
//           . "`invoiceItem_price`,"
//           . " `invoiceItem_totPrice`, "
//           . "`invoice_ID`) "
//           . "VALUES(:invoiceItem_itemID ,"
//           . ":invoiceItem_qty,:invoiceItem_itemPrice,:invoiceItem_totPrice,:invoice_ID)";
//    $qry1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);
//    
//       $qry1->execute(array(':invoiceItem_itemID'=>$invoiceItem_itemID,
//           ':invoiceItem_qty' => $invoiceItem_qty, 
//           ':invoiceItem_price' => $invoiceItem_price, 
//           ':invoiceItem_totPrice' => $invoiceItem_totPrice,
//           ':invoice_ID' => $invoice_ID));



    }


// add main values to invoice table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_invoice`(`invoice_ID`, `inoice_subTot`, `invoice_grandTot`, `invoice_tax`, `invoice_discount`, `tbl_employee_NIC`, `tbl_employee_tbl_branch_branch_ID`)"
            . "VALUES (:invoice_ID,:inoice_subTot,:invoice_grandTot,:invoice_tax,:invoice_discount,:tbl_employee_NIC,:tbl_employee_tbl_branch_branch_ID)";
    $qry = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $qry->execute(array(':invoice_ID'=>$invoice_ID,':inoice_subTot' => $inoice_subTot, ':invoice_grandTot' => $invoice_grandTot, ':invoice_tax' => $invoice_tax, ':invoice_discount' => $invoice_discount, ':tbl_employee_NIC' => $_SESSION['username'], ':tbl_employee_tbl_branch_branch_ID' => $_SESSION['Branch']));


    // ./add main values to invoice table
    $_SESSION['SUCCESS'][] =  " Successfully Saved!";
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $ex->getMessage();
}
//header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

In above code data will be added to the invoicetable without any error.and

```
   echo 'ITEM ID'.$invoiceItem_itemID.'<BR/>'; 
   echo 'QUANTITY'.$invoiceItem_qty.'<BR/>';
   echo 'ITEM PRICE'.$invoiceItem_itemPrice.'<BR/>';
   echo 'ITEM TOTAL'.$invoiceItem_totPrice.'<BR/>';
  echo $invoice_ID ;
```

That part also correctly printed . but when i uncomment the commented part in the code invoice table or invoice item table will not be added.

could anyone please help me to solve this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in `:invoiceItem_itemPrice` vs `:invoiceItem_price`

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO `tbl_invoiceitem`(`invoiceItem_itemID`,"
    . " `invoiceItem_qty`, "
    . "`invoiceItem_price`,"
    . " `invoiceItem_totPrice`, "
    . "`invoice_ID`) "
    . "VALUES(:invoiceItem_itemID ,"
    . ":invoiceItem_qty,:invoiceItem_Price,:invoiceItem_totPrice,:invoice_ID)";
$qry1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);

$qry1->execute(array(
    ':invoiceItem_itemID'   => $invoiceItem_itemID,
    ':invoiceItem_qty'      => $invoiceItem_qty,
    ':invoiceItem_Price'    => $invoiceItem_price,
    ':invoiceItem_totPrice' => $invoiceItem_totPrice,
    ':invoice_ID'           => $invoice_ID
));
```

Comment: Thanks you very very much ... !